# Passport as an authentication service

Tags: passport.js, passport-facebook

Passport as a server running independently and UI (Angular) as another separate instance. All along I have seen implementations where I have seen the authentication modules closely coupled to UI, meaning its in the same container and port.

I am trying to implement an authentication service which will act as a authentication provider to my UI clients and handle everything through HTTP calls.

For now, I have achieved considerable success trying to connect to Passport from UI and redirect the flow to FB, do the login on FB and pass the token as URL parameter to the UI. Then UI interacts with passport using a REST API with the token and gets the User details which is the principal object.

I want to have this as a service because I want it to be the central place of social authentication in my organisation. And anyone can integrate with it just by being in the whitelisted hosts.

Let me know if there are better implementations.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tanzil,

I am not sure if you have a solution for this nowadays, but I want to share for helps who need something like it. Take a look at "passport-service", that promises providing these capabilities.

NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-service

Github: https://github.com/binocarlos/passport-service

You can run it using Docker:

`docker run -d \
  -p 80:80 \
  --link mongo:mongo \
  -e HOSTNAME=172.17.1.168 \
  -e MONGO_SERVICE_HOST=mongo \
  binocarlos/passport-service`

Enjoy.